# 504 Gateway Timeout when running flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run my flask appliation using AWS Elastic Beanstalk but I'm facing the 504 Gateway Timeout problem.

I already tried several approaches that I found, but nothing works :/

Currently, my configs are this way:

.ebextensions/python.config

```
option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
        WSGIPath: application:application

packages:
 yum:
    python3-devel: []
    gcc: []
    mariadb-devel: []

files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi_custom.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

container_commands:
    01_restart_nginx:
     command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

.platform/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf

```
keepalive_timeout 3600s;
proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 3600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
```

In the log file, the erros appearing this way:

/var/log/nginx/error.log

***1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream**

/var/log/web.stdout.log

**[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT**